# Python argparse - option with options to dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, argparse

I am trying to parse some options with argparse.  I have found some similar problems discussed and found what I thought was a similar issue with a sensible solution given by Owen in [Options with Options with Python argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537465/options-with-options-with-python-argparse)

I want to be able to specify, for example:

```
script.py infile --line <path to file1> beglab='str1' endlab='str2' 
                 --line <path to file2>  
                 --line <path to file3> beglab='str3' 
                 outfile
```

--line  can be specified multiple times.  Initially I had no extra arguments for the line option and I was able to create a list of the files without a problem using:

```
parser.add_argument("--line", action='append')
```

Now I need to optionally add labels to go with the lines.  There can be 0, 1 or 2 labels associated with a given line as shown above.  This is why I felt the example in the link provided seemed appropriate, unfortunately when I try:

```
parser.add_argument("--line", action='append', nargs="+")
```

And run:

```
script.py infile --line somefile beglab='A' endlab='B' 
                 --line otherfile beglab='a' endlab='b' outfile
```

or

```
script.py infile --line somefile outfile
```

I get an error stating that there are too few arguments.  If I remove the --line options from the command so I have just the positional ones, it works, so I know I haven't missed anything required.  So I went and I read up on the nargs options.  If --line is specified, it must have at least the filename, therefore I think that `nargs='+'` is the appropriate option, it looks about right in the help `[--line LINE [LINE ...]]`, so I am really confused about where this error has come from.

I am happy to consider alternative methods of dealing with this, I just liked the simplicity of providing the inputs like this and creating a dictionary with them.

Comment: The `'+'` is greedy, allocating all strings to `--line` (till the end or the next `--`).  Thus it leaves nothing for `outfile`.  There's bug/issue that has explored reserving a value for the following positional, but that won't be changed soon.  This has also been covered in other SO questions.  But the accepted answer is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser you want to build is ambiguous. If `endlab='b'` is optional, then argparse can't tell if the operator intends that `outfile` is a parameter to `--line` or a positional argument.

You don't have to change your parser, but you do have to change your command line:

Try:

```
script.py infile outfile
          --line somefile beglab='A' endlab='B' 
          --line otherfile beglab='a' endlab='b'
```

Or:

```
script.py infile 
          --line somefile beglab='A' endlab='B' 
          --line otherfile beglab='a' endlab='b' 
          --
          outfile
```

Comment: I almost asked in my question how it knew when to stop. So the answer is it doesn't and that actually that explains the error message! Such a simple thing really.

Comment: I have just noticed that your first example has an extra "outfile" at the end which needs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks, @emmalg. I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to accomplish this with argparse, but for simplicity, I would consider doing something like:

`--line <path_to_file>,<beglab>,<endlab>`

And then parse the argument either in code or using argparse's custom type functionality.  You can have the custom type function return a dict like `{'filepath':'<path_to_file>', 'beglab':'<beglab>', 'endlab':'<endlab>'}`